# Can I have a generic type bound that requires that type to be a trait?

Tags: rust

I want to declare a generic function that accepts trait objects *and only trait objects*. I want this because I want to type erase these and pass them as `TraitObject` objects across an ABI boundary.

A function written like this will fail to compile...

```
fn f<T: ?Sized>(t: &T) -> std::raw::TraitObject {
    unsafe { std::mem::transmute(t) }
}
```

... with the following error:

```
error[E0512]: transmute called with differently sized types: &T (pointer to T) to std::raw::TraitObject (128 bits)
```

I understand why the compiler complains of different sizes: `&T` can be a pointer to a concrete type (like `&i32`), which is a single pointer (64 bits), or a trait object (like `&Display`), which is going to be two pointers with the same layout as `std::raw::TraitObject` (128 bits).

This function should be fine as long as `&T` is a trait object, i.e. `T` is a trait. Is there a way to express this requirement?

Comment: And to be clear, it can't be a *specific* trait object? Cause `fn f(t: &SomeTrait)` would always be a trait object.

Comment: @Shepmaster Correct. Without the generics, everything is dandy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you [use `transmute_copy` instead](https://play.rust-lang.org/?code=%23!%5Bfeature(raw)%5D%0A%0Ause%20std%3A%3Araw%3A%3ATraitObject%3B%0Ause%20std%3A%3Amem%3B%0A%0Atrait%20Foo%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20fn%20f(%26self)%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Astruct%20Bar%3B%0A%0Aimpl%20Foo%20for%20Bar%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20fn%20f(%26self)%20%7B%20println!(%22ok%22)%20%7D%0A%7D%0A%0Afn%20erase%3C%27a%2C%20T%3A%20%3FSized%3E(r%3A%20%26%27a%20T)%20-%3E%20TraitObject%20%7B%20unsafe%20%7B%20mem%3A%3Atransmute_copy(%26r)%20%7D%20%7D%0Afn%20recover%3C%27a%2C%20T%3A%20%3FSized%3E(r%3A%20TraitObject)%20-%3E%20%26%27a%20T%20%7B%20unsafe%20%7B%20mem%3A%3Atransmute_copy(%26r)%20%7D%20%7D%20%0A%0Afn%20erase_foo%3C%27a%3E(r%3A%20%26%27a%20Foo)%20-%3E%20TraitObject%20%7B%20unsafe%20%7B%20mem%3A%3Atransmute(r)%20%7D%20%7D%0Afn%20recover_foo%3C%27a%3E(r%3A%20TraitObject)%20-%3E%20%26%27a%20Foo%20%7B%20unsafe%20%7B%20mem%3A%3Atransmute(r)%20%7D%20%7D%20%0A%0Afn%20main()%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20let%20r%3A%20%26Foo%20%3D%20%26Bar%3B%0A%20%20%20%20let%20x%20%3D%20erase(r)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20let%20xf%20%3D%20erase_foo(r)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20println!(%22%7B%3A%3F%7D%20%7B%3A%3F%7D%22%2C%20x.data%2C%20x.vtable)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20println!(%22%7B%3A%3F%7D%20%7B%3A%3F%7D%22%2C%20xf.data%2C%20xf.vtable)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20let%20y%3A%20%26Foo%20%3D%20recover(x)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20let%20yf%20%3D%20recover_foo(xf)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20y.f()%3B%0A%20%20%20%20yf.f()%3B%0A%7D&version=nightly&backtrace=0), you can have the compiler ignore the size mismatches. This, however, means you have to handle such issues yourself, by e.g. checking the size yourself and perhaps panicking if there's a mismatch. Not doing so can result in undefined behaviour.

```
fn f<T: ?Sized>(t: &T) -> std::raw::TraitObject {
    assert!(std::mem::size_of::<&T>() == std::mem::size_of::<std::raw::TraitObject>());
    unsafe { std::mem::transmute_copy(&r) }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

It is impossible to prove a negative... but as far as I know the answer is no, sorry.

The representation of `TraitObject` is unstable, notably because in the future Rust might be able to tack on multiple virtual pointers to a single data pointer (representing `&(Display + Eq)` for example).

In the mean time, I usually use low-level memory tricks to read the virtual pointer and data pointer then build the `TraitObject` myself; guarded by a call to `mem::size_of` to ensure that `&T` has the right size for 2 `*mut ()` because `?Sized` means `Sized` or not (and not `!Sized`).

Comment: I've just realized that using `transmute_copy`  instead of `transmute` is enough to have the function compile, and it seems to work properly (as long as T is a trait, of course) https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=072c6e41e3887b81062c5e2672baefc3&version=nightly&backtrace=0. Is that the kind of low-level memory tricks you were thinking of?

Comment: (On a side note: JESUS I have 100k+ rep and I cannot post a shortened playground link in a comment for some ungodly reason)

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes: No it wasn't; it's much better actually. I am surprised it works with unsized types though since there is not `?Sized` bound [in the documentation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/mem/fn.transmute_copy.html). I encourage you to post this as an answer, it's much better than fiddling around with pointers. I also encourage you to use a size check to check that at run-time that the passed-in data is *really* 128 bits (and not 64) since `transmute_copy` doesn't check (and has undefined behavior if it needs to read past the bounds of the source object).

Comment: Yeah, I would add the size check if I take this approach. I just didn't do it in the test.

Comment: Also note that it doesn't work with unsized types. `Foo` is a trait, hence unsized, but `&Foo` is a trait object and thus sized. The thing `transmute_copy` copies is `&Foo` not `Foo`. (I.e. the argument is actually `&&Foo` in my example)

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes: Ah! That must be the error I made: I must have forgotten the `&` in front of the reference (called `transmute_copy(r)` instead of `transmute_copy(&r)`), thus getting the compiler to complain about an unsized `T`...

Answer (score 1):

I *believe* [the answer is "no"](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/raw/struct.TraitObject.html):

> There is **no way** to refer to all trait objects generically

(emphasis mine)